# How could I create a sub-query in cakePHP?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-model, cakephp-2.3

How could I create a sub-query in cakePHP with find method? For example:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE table2.field1 = table1.id) AS count
FROM table1
WHERE table1.field1 = 'value'
```

!!! **table2.field1 = table1.id** !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this one of two ways:

#### 1. Use $this->Model->query(...)

This allows you execute SQL directly using the query you posted above but be aware that it can make your application quite brittle if the database schema were to change. Probably the fastest.([Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query))

*Example*

```
$this->Model1->query("SELECT * FROM model;");
```

#### 2. Separate the Calls

This is probably not as fast as option 1 but it does give you the ability to break your query down into a number of steps. You're also unlikely to get SQL injection which is potential risk with option 1.

*Example*

```
$model1s = $this->Model1->find
(
    'all', 
    array
    (
        'conditions' => array('Model1.field1' => 'value')
    )
);
foreach($model1s as $model1)
{
    $model1['model2_count'] = $this->Model2->find
    (
        'count', 
        array
        (
            'conditions' => array
            (
                'Model2.field1' => $model1['id']
            )
        )
     );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just for addition, you can build subquery using Cake's ORM. It will be more easy. Please read [CakePHP retrieving data doc](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#sub-queries)

In general you can use `buildStatement()` method of `DataSource` object. You can save all logic, including pagination etc.